# Dynamic table view construction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is a rails 3.1 app, and I am a bit of a noob with regards to Ruby
and I am sure there is a better way to do this.

I have a mongoDB with a variable length record, so the data might look like this:

```
     name | type | age  | foo | bis  | boz 
     ------------------------------------------------
a    data |  -   | data |  -  | data | - 
b     -   | data |  -   |  -  | data | data
c     -   |  -   |  -   | data|  -   | _
```

where the "-" is no value.

data looks like:

```
[_id: "a", name: "data", age: "data", bis: "data"]
[_id: "b", type: "data", bis: "data", boz: "data"]
[_id: "c", foo:  "data"]
```

I want to display this data in a table in my view
I can get an array of all (possible) table headers
with something like this:

```
@trains = Train.page(params[:page] || 1).per(50)
@a = []
@header_array = @trains.each {|train| @a.push(train.attributes.keys)}
@header_values = @a.uniq.to_a
```

but how can I loop thru the data to build the data rows of each record and ensure they line up in the correct column of the table header? Maybe there's a better way to generate the whole table.
I also don't know what the attributes of each record might be, so given a result set the table headers would be dynamically built every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the header values in `@header_values` so you could drive the display using that instead of using each Train to drive its own display; something like this:

```
<% @trains.each do |t| %>
    <tr>
        <% @header_values.each do |k| %>
            <td><%= t[k] || '-' %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

You might need to adjust `t[k] || '-'` to match your data and possibly format the value depending on `k`. You also might want to order `@header_values` in some specific way to produce sensible output.

Comment: adjusted original question, I can't match on '_' as the record length is variable

Comment: @sysconfig: I don't understand your comment. You have all possible columns in `@header_values` so you iterate on that, if a particular train has that property then use `t[k]`, if it doesn't then use `'-'`.